# OpenCV parallel splitting

Tags: c++, opencv, parallel-processing

I have a three channel image and want to split it with the function split.

```
void function(Mat modifiedImage, Mat originalImage, int rows, int cols)
{

   Mat channels[3];
   cv::split(originalImage, channels);

   Mat blue = channels[0];
   Mat green = channels[1];
   Mat red = channels[2];

}
```

I heard that the split function can be used in a parallel mode. How can I do this?

Comment: Which system are you running on? Windows? Linux? OSX?

Comment: I use Windows. But I thought it shouldn't depend on the operating system.

Comment: Threading depends on operating system, since you are running Windows you can use WinAPI's own `CreateThread ( )` function, or you can download POSIX threads and use POSIX's `pthread_create ( )` function. 

If you need help with writing the code, I can give you an example when I get some time to write a answer.

Comment: @BufferOverflow Looks like c++ code to me. Threading has been in the standard since C++11. If you're stuck with an old compiler, there's always boost. Little reason to deal with non-portable low level APIs.

Comment: I know about C++ 11 threading and POSIX. But I don't want to parallel my program manually. To be more precise, the question is about existing the parallel version of the function split or something like this. It would be very logical if there were one.

Answer (score 0):

Really late getting here, but you can use `cv::extractChannel` which only extracts one channel. You can then use the openCV `parallel_for_' to extract each channel in parallel.